# User registration endpoint in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework. I've written the following view to register a new user to the system.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
def create_user(request):
    email = request.DATA['email']
    password = request.DATA['password']
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        false = False
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            'success': False,
            'reason': 'User with this email already exists'
        }), content_type='application/json')
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        user = User(email=email, username=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        profile.save()
        profile_serialized = UserProfileSerializer(profile)
        token = Token(user=user)
        token.save()
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
            'success': True,
            'key': token.key,
            'user_profile': profile_serialized.data
        }), content_type='application/json')
```

Is there a better, slightly more secure way, of creating a user registration api in DRF that doesn't leave the endpoint so open to sql injection?

Comment: Yes. [Validation docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me to digress a little, but I can't help but wonder use could have gotten away with far less code, than you have if you had created a serializer and used a class-based view. Besides, if you had just created email as EmailField of serializer it would have automatically guaranteed the validation of email. Since you are using orm interface, risk of sql injection is much less than raw query in my opinion.

Sample Code:-

```
class UserList(CreateAPIView):

 serializer_class = UserSerializer


class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):

  email = serializers.EmailField()
  raw_password = serializers.CharField()
```

Something on these lines, Obviously I couldn't write entire code.

Comment: Let me know in case of any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the email in your serializer using the `validate-email-address` module like this:

```
from validate_email_address import validate_email
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_email(self, value):
        if not validate_email(value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not a valid email.")
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

Also, you might consider a packaged auth/registration solution like [Djoser](https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser).